# To create a new table with the sums of values by person

Tags: postgresql, create-table

I use the following code to create a new table with the sums of distances by person, but it doesn't give me what I want. For example: If we have in the table "etappen" for a person (householdnumber=10, personnumber=1) following distances: **40** and **15**. The line in the new table should be seen as follows: **10 - 1 - 55**

```
CREATE VIEW newtable("householdnumber","personnumber",sum)   
AS SELECT "householdnumber","personnumber", SUM("distance")
FROM etappen WHERE    
GROUP BY "householdnumber","personnumber" ;
```

Do you have an idea about what I can do?

[The example(data) can be found here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/57mAK.png)

Comment: [edit] your question and add some sample data

Comment: Rather than an image, please paste the data as text in the question itself; it will make it much easier for people to use that test data in examples and answers. And don't forget to include both the *current* and the *expected* result, so we can understand what the problem is.